# CodeIgniter and layouts?

Tags: codeigniter, layout

What CodeIgniter library can provide this funcionality??

http://media.railscasts.com/videos/008_content_for.mov

It seems so simple on rails but I just cant find a simple way to achieve this on codeigniter.. please help.. I hate having to insert my styles or javascript in the body of the document

Comment: Without actually downloading or sitting through that video we have no idea what it is you're after. Perhaps you can update the question to explain what this functionality is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hate templates like Smarty or http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/

Using my own implementation of Zend-like layout.

Add hook /application/hooks/Layout.php:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 *
 */
class Layout {

    function render() {

        global $OUT;
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $output = $CI->output->get_output();
        if (!isset($CI->layout)) {
            $CI->layout = "default";
        }
        if ($CI->layout != false) {
            if (!preg_match('/(.+).php$/', $CI->layout)) {
                $CI->layout .= '.php';
            }

            $requested = BASEPATH . '../application/layouts/' . $CI->layout;
            $default = BASEPATH . '../application/layouts/default.php';

            if (file_exists($requested)) {
                $layout = $CI->load->file($requested, true);
            } else {
                $layout = $CI->load->file($default, true);
            }

            $view = str_replace("{content}", $output, $layout);
            $view = str_replace("{title}", $CI->title, $view);

            $scripts = "";
            $styles = "";
            $metas = "";
            if (count($CI->meta) > 0) {     // Массив с мета-тегами
                $metas = implode("\n", $CI->meta);
            }
            if (count($CI->scripts) > 0) {  // Массив со скриптами
                foreach ($CI->scripts as $script) {
                    $scripts .= "<script type='text/javascript' src='" . base_url() . "js/" . $script . ".js'></script>";
                }
            }
            if (count($CI->styles) > 0) {   // Массив со стилями
                foreach ($CI->styles as $style) {
                    $styles .= "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" . base_url() . "css/" . $style . ".css' />";
                }
            }

            if (count($CI->parts) > 0) {    // Массив с частями страницы
                foreach ($CI->parts as $name => $part) {
                    $view = str_replace("{" . $name . "}", $part, $view);
                }
            }
            $view = str_replace("{metas}", $metas, $view);
            $view = str_replace("{scripts}", $scripts, $view);
            $view = str_replace("{styles}", $styles, $view);
            $view = preg_replace("/{.*?}/ims", "", $view); // Подчищаем пустые неподгруженные части шаблона
        } else {
            $view = $output;
        }
        $OUT->_display($view);
    }

}

?>
```

Then enable hooks in your /application/config/config.php:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

After that add to /application/config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['display_override'][] = array('class' => 'Layout',
    'function' => 'render',
    'filename' => 'Layout.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

Create folder /application/layouts/

Create file /application/layouts/default.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        {metas}
        {scripts}
        {styles}
        <link rel="icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= base_url() ?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="head">
            {head}
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            {content}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Use it from controller:

```
class main extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->parts[head] = $this->load->view("frontend/global/header.php", null, true);
        $this->scripts = array("JQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min", "JQuery/form", "Core", "Frontend");
        $this->styles = array("style");
        $this->title = "Blah blah";
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('frontend/index.php');
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Eazery, I am trying to use your approach with CodeIgniter 2.1.3 for managing my site layout, but unfortunately getting some errors, so can you please help me out to solve those issues.

I am seeing an error message of "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method BaseController::Controller()" in my php error log file, if I comment the corresponding code line(parent::Controller();) of my controller then getting 2 errors of "Use of undefined constant head - assumed 'head'" and "Undefined property: Home::$load" in the browser it self.

Is your code need to be adjusted to work with CI V2.1.3.

Answer (score 4):

I've achieved this in the past using this [Template Library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/). From the documentation:

> The Template library, written for the
>   CodeIgniter PHP-framework, is a
>   wrapper for CI’s View implementation.
>   Template is a reaction to the numerous
>   questions from the CI community
>   regarding how one would display
>   multiple views for one controller, and
>   how to embed “views within views” in a
>   standardized fashion. In addition,
>   Template provides extra Views loading
>   capabilities, the ability to utilize
>   any template parser (like Smarty), and
>   shortcuts for including CSS,
>   JavaScript, and other common elements
>   in your final rendered HTML.

Specifically, check out the library's [additional utilities](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#utilities). It allows you to put something like this in your controller:

```
$this->template->add_js('js/YourJavascriptFile.js');
```

or

```
$this->template->add_js('alert("Hello!");', 'embed');
```

> Echo `$_scripts` in your template
>   (preferably in the `<head>` section) to
>   utilize JavaScript added via this
>   method.

Similarly, you can do the same with your CSS:

```
$this->template->add_css('css/main.css');
$this->template->add_css('#logo {display: block}', 'embed', 'print');
```

..and simply echo `$_styles` in your `<head>` section.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats pretty good but I wish I could do it in my views..

Answer (score 2):

Check out Twig - it supports "inheritance" (instead of the traditional include header, include footer, etc)

http://www.twig-project.org/

CodeIgniter helper:

http://github.com/jamiepittock/codeigniter-twig
or
http://github.com/MaherSaif/codeigniter-twig

(haven't tried either, but looks like the latter is a fork w/the latest commits)

Comment: I have tried this and can confirm that it works http://github.com/MaherSaif/codeigniter-twig

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with finding a advance layout library as well,
so i wrote my own version which also fits your need (using YAML file).

#### Features

- Manage layouts, page title, metas, css and js with YAML file for cleaner and lighter controllers.
- Default configs can be overwritten in controller configs. So that you can split your css and js into smaller files for more flexible design.
- Combine and minify css and js files in production mode for faster page loading.

#### Usage

```
  // in the controller
  $this->view->render();
```

This lib will get the layout, view, page title, css, js, metas from your YAML configs

#### Documentation

- Please see [this post](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/codeigniter-view-library/) for more detail

#### download

- Download source code from [Github](https://github.com/dreamerslab/ci.view/zipball/master)